# How do i create and read External table in GPDB

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, hawq

We have small gpdb cluster. When i am trying to create and read on my first External table using gpfdist protocol.

**Getting error at reading of external table  :**
that is

```
prod=# select * from ext_table
prod-# ;
ERROR:  connection with gpfdist failed for gpfdist://gpmasterhost:8080/demo/gp_RevenueReport_stg0.txt. effective url: http://gpmasterhost:8080/demo/gp_RevenueReport_stg0.txt. error code = 111 (Connection refused)  (seg0 slice1 datanode2 40000 pid=5402)
prod=#
```

**We tried DDL command for external table :**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_table
(
  "ID" bigint,
  "time" timestamp without time zone,
   )
 LOCATION (
    'gpfdist://gpmasterhost:8080/demo/gp_RevenueReport_stg0.txt'
)
 FORMAT 'TEXT' (delimiter ';' null '' escape '~' )
ENCODING 'UTF8';
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the gpfdist process on "gpmasterhost" listening on port 8080 and serving files that include the directory demo which contains gp_RevenueReport_stg0.txt.

```
gpfdist -p 8080 -d path_to_demo &
```

Comment: I ran command it says and still executing :[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ 2016-06-16 14:49:05 32581 INFO Before opening listening sockets - following listening sockets are available:
2016-06-16 14:49:05 32581 INFO IPV6 socket: [::]:8080
2016-06-16 14:49:05 32581 INFO IPV4 socket: 0.0.0.0:8080
2016-06-16 14:49:05 32581 INFO Trying to open listening socket:

2016-06-16 14:49:05 32581 INFO Opening listening socket succeeded
2016-06-16 14:49:05 32581 INFO Trying to open listening socket:
2016-06-16 14:49:05 32581 INFO IPV4 socket: 0.0.0.0:8080
Serving HTTP on port 8080, directory /home/gpadmin/demo

Comment: [root@mdw ~]# ps aux |grep gpfdist
root      9417  0.0  0.0 103244   868 pts/1    R+   14:57   0:00 grep gpfdist
gpadmin  32581  0.0  0.0  27148  1692 pts/0    S    14:49   0:00 gpfdist -p 8080 -d /home/gpadmin/demo
[root@mdw ~]#

Comment: when i am reading the file that is select * from ext_table getting this :ERROR:  http response code 404 from gpfdist (gpfdist://gphostname:8080/demo/gp_RevenueReport_stg0.txt): HTTP/1.0 404 file not found (url.c:352)  (seg0 slice1 datanode1:40000 pid=6185) (cdbdisp.c:1326)

Comment: The directory specified in the `-d` option will be the root of the gpfdist server.  

If you data dir is:  
    `/my/data/dir/demo/gp_RevenueReport_stg0.txt`
  
Then the gpfdist command line should be:  
    `gpfdist -p 8080 -d /my/data/dir &`

Comment: got it . It means we need to only put /home/gpadmin and again  i have to run this command  again .gpfdist -p 8080 -d /home/gpadmin & . should i kill exsting gpfdist process which is running on dir /home/gpadmin/demo

Comment: prod=# select * from schema.ext_table ;
 ID | time
----+------
(0 rows)

Comment: Thanks alot to both of you. when i  have to take load from  hdfs into greenplum . this protocol will not  work ?

Comment: When loading from hdfs, you have to use the "gphdfs" protocol instead of "gpfdist".  You won't use gpfdist at all when reading from hdfs.

Comment: checked with gphdfs protocol and  have created readable external file in gpdb.Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon had said, you will need to run gpfdist on your "gpmasterhost" system.

However, based on your notes gpfdist is running in your demo directory:

ps aux |grep gpfdist root 9417 0.0 0.0 103244 868 pts/1 R+ 14:57 0:00 grep gpfdist gpadmin 32581 0.0 0.0 27148 1692 pts/0 S 14:49 0:00 gpfdist -p 8080 -d /home/gpadmin/demo

So you will either need to change your EXTERNAL definition to (note I am not using the demo directory):

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_table
(
  "ID" bigint,
  "time" timestamp without time zone,
   )
 LOCATION (
    'gpfdist://gpmasterhost:8080/gp_RevenueReport_stg0.txt'
)
 FORMAT 'TEXT' (delimiter ';' null '' escape '~' )
ENCODING 'UTF8';

Or run gpfdist up one level (/home/gpadmin) with no modification to your external table.

Comment: Also gpfdist is just lighthttp daemon, is my understanding, so you can test out with wget as well to ensure you can connect and pull the file(s) you want outside of greenplum.

Comment: Thanks i am going to use /home/gpadmin up level .